# C# Best Practices: Unit Testing code that refers to utilizes other methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following code:

```
    public static String GetHashString(this HashAlgorithm algorithm, Stream inputStream)
    {
        if (algorithm == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullError("algorithm");

        if (inputStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullError("inputStream");

        Byte[] bytes = algorithm.ComputeHash(inputStream);

        //Convert the bytes into a hash string
        String result = ...;
        return result;
    }
```

I'm wondering a couple of things:

1. Looking at the Microsoft.NET4
   `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream
   inputStream)` method I can see that
   there is an exception that
   could come back. Is it a best
   practice in this situation to wrap
   the line `Byte[] bytes =
   algoirthm.ComputeHash(inputStream)`
   with a try-catch block? I ask
   because it seems to me that if that
   line throws an exception I can let calls
   to my extension handle the error
   catching. Or, is it supposed to be
   try-catch wrapped with a simple
   throw.
2. Also, when unit testing, do I unit
   test for ALL possible exceptions,
   including ones that could come from
   other method? Particularly in this
   case... is it best practice? In this
   situation I would only need to
   expect an `ObjectDisposeException`.
   But I'm wondering about situations
   where I call a method that could throw
   back 10 different exceptions. Since I'm
   not really changing my output based
   on these exceptions, I don't think
   it's necessary to unit test all different
   types of failures that lead to the same
   result. Am I right for thinking this?
3. And lastly, I wonder if it's
   necessary to even check for
   inputStream being null if the
   `HashAlgorithm.computeHash(Stream
   inputStream)` method doesn't even do
   so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remember that you should test your code and not the .NET Framework,

I would not put Byte[] bytes = algoirthm.ComputeHash(inputStream) in a try-catch block, the code who is calling your method will have to handle that.

When unit testing you could test some use case and make sure that with valid input no exceptions are thrown and with invalid input the excepted exceptions are thown.

I think your code is ok and exactly because .NET throws an exception if inputStream is null, you are doing this check and throwing **ArgumentNullException** if the calling code passes a null inputStream

Davide.

Comment: Well, if .NET throws an exception if the inputStream is null, should I even bother checking for it? Should I just let .NET throw it's exception instead of me doing so?

Comment: It really depends on the overall design of your application, do you have a global exception handler which catches and logs all unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Not yet, but I plan to have some type of logging, though I questioned about having the "commons" library for my applications integrated with some type of logger. I figured I should leave the logging up to the application.

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing this method, you want to ensure that given valid (correct) input you are getting correct (expected) output. You can't possibly handle every situation, so just handle the ones that are important and are likely to occur. You should handle invalid input gracefully (i.e. like when you threw exceptions for `null` input values) and test how your method handles invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a `try...catch` only if you want to treat the exception somehow (even if that means throwing a new exception - but use the `innerException` parameter in that case). If there is nothing you can do in case of an exception, there is no need use it.
2. To start thinking of every possible way some piece of code can go wrong is the way to madness. You *must* test all possible successful executions, you *should* test the most common errors, but sometimes you just can't test every possible situation. Use your own judgment.
3. If it is impossible for a .NET method to return null, I guess it is ok to not test that possibility. BTW some tools (like ReSharper) could help you with that kind of decision.

Still about item 3, that kind of test you're doing is a precondition, and that style of programming is called [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). There is a new .NET framework that helps defining preconditions, postconditions and invariants - I guess you should take a look at it:

[DevLabs: Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)